# -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; not working on android 2.3.5

Tags: android, css

wondering if anybody knows the reason that on android 2.3.5 the -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; does not work, any workaround? im already declaring oper separate each property of the animation that solved the animation not working at all but still this fill mode is not responding. tks in advance.
my actual workaround code and below how does not work in this android 2.3.5

```
.a{
-webkit-animation-duration:2.7s; 
-webkit-animation-name:a; 
-webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in; 
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;

}

 .a{-webkit-animation:a 2.7s ease-in forwards;}

@-webkit-keyframes a{
0% {}
90% {top:370px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
95% {top:360px;left:255px;}
100%{top:370px;left:245px;}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually asked about it here: [CSS3 animation-fill-mode polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534228/css3-animation-fill-mode-polyfill)

Check some nice replies they gave me

---

Android 2.3.5 `animations` [compatibility is partial](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation), so you probably need a JavaScript fallback

Comment: tks, i ve been reading and though they are nice solutions, i cant make to work adding two animations as one solution there 'animation: waitandhide 2s 0s, show 2s 2s;'. in this android at least no animation is shown if more than one declared

Comment: finally made it with jQuery .animation()

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.  For Android try:

```
-webkit-animation-play-state
```

As specified here: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp)

That resolved the issue on JellyBean