# CSS animation-fill-mode on other browsers than Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, webkit

Chrome's webkit is the only one (as I know) supporting animation-fill-mode.

(`-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards`)

On my ***[site](http://artotek.fi/m_index.html)*** the animation works just fine when you load the page on Chrome.
However, as it's a mobile site, it's a problem that it doesn't work outside Chrome.

I'd like a pure CSS solution if possible.

Comment: As of MDN it is supported by all modern browsers. Have you also included the other vendor prefixes? See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode (Also keep an eye on that big yellow box at the top "This is an experimental technology")

Comment: My site is designed for mobile, and the compatibility  of that with mobile browsers is unknown... Didn't work 2.3.4 Android Dolphin Browser.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598930/webkit-animation-fill-modeforwards-not-working-on-android-2-3-5 (and from the answers it looks like it can be done with jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

For other browser you could use :

```
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;  /* it works with Chrome */
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;  /* works with Mozilla Firefox */
     -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;  /* works with IE */
      -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;  /* works with Opera */
         animation-fill-mode: forwards;  /* should work with all browser .... in theory */
```

You can find more details on prefixes here :

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp

Have a nice day