# Text blink from one color to another css or jquery

Tags: jquery, css, blink

I would want to blink a text with two different colors:

For example: blinking a text white-green-white-green-white-green

I don't mind if jQuery or CSS.

Comment: `<blink>` was retired for a good reason.

Comment: Tell us what you've tried and we will be able to help you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605698/text-blinking-jquery

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Against my better judgement LOL...You will need to adjust for cross-browser compatibility with webkit, etc

**EDITTED TO WORK WITH ALL BROWSERS**

```
 <a href="#"> text</a>


 /* css */

 a {
   animation-duration: 400ms;
   animation-name: blink;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes blink {
   from {
      opacity: 1;
   }
   to {
      opacity: 0;
   }
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jzT8E/6/)

Comment: Just fyi, it doesn't work in my up to date version of chrome without adding the vendor prefix `-webkit-`. You should probably mention that somewhere.

Comment: Yes, in chrome it does not work.

Comment: @onbermejo It does now. Perhaps you can close this question as an answer now?

Comment: And I know that it is horrible, but it has been imposible to change... Thank you again. ;)

Comment: this is "blink-fadeout" or "flashing" but not "blink"

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/8Xhzt/12/

no support for IE 9: animation-iteration-count
**Note** to support non-supporting current browsers you  can use Modernizr: 
See [How do I normalize CSS3 Transition functions across browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023514/how-do-i-normalize-css3-transition-functions-across-browsers)
[CSS3 animation-fill-mode polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534228/css3-animation-fill-mode-polyfill)

```
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
   from { color: green; }
   to { color: white; }
  }
 @-moz-keyframes blink {
   from { color: green; }
   to { color: white; }
 }
 @-ms-keyframes blink {
   from { color: green; }
   to { color: white; }
 }
 @-o-keyframes blink {
   from { color: green; }
   to { color: white; }
 }
 @keyframes blink {
   from { color: green; }
   to { color: white; }
 }

 .blink {
    color: green;
    -webkit-animation: blink 2s 3 alternate;
    -moz-animation: blink 2s 3 alternate;  
    -ms-animation: blink 2s 3 alternate;  
    -o-animation: blink 2s 3 alternate;  
    animation: blink 2s 3 alternate;   
 }
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks.
Do you know how could i do it infinite?